# Treenode populating blank nodes C#

Tags: c#, .net, treeview

I have some code that creates treenodes for treeviews I have.  Everything works fine for the two foreach loops, but the third one with 'warnNode' doesn't render the node text - just the connecting lines for the treeview.

I've stepped through the code and see the valid text and child nodes in warnNode and I have no idea why this wouldn't work.

```
        foreach (FundFamilySum ff in allCredits.FundFamilyCredits)
        {
            TreeNode fundFamilyNode =  this.tvFundFamily.Nodes.Add(ff.FundFamilyName);

            AddNodes(ff.BrokerCreditList, fundFamilyNode);
            fundFamilyNode.ExpandAll();
        }

        foreach (FundSum f in allCredits.FundCredits)
        {
            TreeNode fundNode = this.tvFund.Nodes.Add(f.FundName);

            AddNodes(f.BrokerCreditList, fundNode);
            fundNode.ExpandAll();
        }

        TreeNode warnNode = this.tvWarnings.Nodes.Add("Warnings");
        foreach (WarningCredit w in allCredits.WarningCredits)
        {
            warnNode.Nodes.Add(string.Format("{0} with {1} - {2} Utilization", w.FundOrFamName, w.Credit.BrokerName, String.Format("{0:0%}", w.Credit.UtilPct)));
            //TreeNode warnChildNode = warnNode.Nodes.Add(w.Credit.BrokerName + " - " + String.Format("{0:0%}", w.Credit.UtilPct) + " Utilization")

        }
        warnNode.ExpandAll();
```

Here is what is rendered, it seems as though there is something there as the highlighted section in blue is the correct size for my text, but the text itself doesn't show.
[image]

Comment: check the forecolor of your treeview. Code looks good.

Answer (score 0):

Forecolor was great, but I deleted this and created a new treeview in the designer and it worked.  Weird, but fixed.